# Error 'KafkaClient' object has no attribute 'poll'

Tags: python

I am trying to use a single DNS name for all available brokers mentioned as an A record in this DNS.

In case the broker to which it is connecting to is down but the DNS entry exists then I want it to poll for the another and different a record in after a particular timeout in the same DNS name which is pointing to a different broker.

```
import socket
from kafka import KafkaClient
broker = KafkaClient("kafka.example")
print(broker.poll())
```

I am using above code just to check the polling but I am getting below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "broker_connection.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(broker.poll())
AttributeError: 'KafkaClient' object has no attribute 'poll'
```

Answer (score 0):

Its is solved. The 'poll' is not in the kafka package it was in the kafka.client. below code works for me.

```
from kafka.client import KafkaClient
```